# Is there a good name for this pointer template?

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a proper name of a class template with the following features:

It's interface would look something like this, where *Foo* is a placeholder for the name I'm looking for.

```
template<typename T> 
struct Foo
{
    T* operator->();
    T* operator*();
}
```

So, it imitates a pointer to an object, much like `std::unique_ptr<>` and `std::shared_ptr<>` do. Unlike them, having a `Foo<T>` to an object doesn't imply ownership over this object. Everything `Foo<T>` does is provide a pointer to this object and, this is the important part, once the object `Foo<T>` points to is deleted both operators return `nullptr` instead of the now invalid pointer.

I'm looking for a descriptive name for this class. Maybe it has intersecting semantics with a well defined pattern I am not aware of?

Comment: How would `Foo` detect that the object is deleted?

Comment: That's not the question ;) I tried to keep the question simple by not describing that, but T could emit an _AboutToBeDeleted_ event. There are other ways, of course.

Comment: [Smart pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer)

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [weak pointer.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference)

It's common in GC languages for cached values that are allowed to be deleted and the map that holds it can detect it and recreate it.

C++ has a `weak_ptr` that works in conjunction with `shared_ptr`. You can assign a `shared_ptr` to a weak_ptr and get the shared_ptr from it again later with `lock` as long as the last shared_ptr hasn't been destroyed yet, after it has then lock returns a shared_ptr that holds a null pointer.